# Browser compatibility jquery trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

trigger click in jquery not working in safari example : http://jsfiddle.net/PgaUq/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(e){
  var file = $("<input type='file' class='fileinput'>").trigger("click");
  $("#files").append(file);
 });
});
```

Comment: Is it because you haven't included jQuery?

Comment: working fine in other browsers(IE,firefox and chrome)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I found hidden objects cannot be clicked in safari with .trigger("click") which was creating the problem.